# Could not perform concurrent requests from mysql db through django ; InterfaceError at url (0, '')

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I've a django app which fetches data from mysql db whenever a request is received.This works fine when request is processed by one user but, when more than user send request, I get a error message saying **"InterfaceError at url (0, '')".**
I'm using Django version 1.9.

As per my research , I included CONN_MAX_AGE in my settings.py but still I got the same error.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        **'CONN_MAX_AGE': None**
    }
}
```

my **models.py**

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='password',db='db_name',port=3306,charset='utf8',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def execute(query):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()
    return data


def trending_assets():

    sql = "select * from media_recommendation_engine.content_table t1 inner join (SELECT movieId,rank from" \
          " media_recommendation_engine.asset_ranks limit 10) t2 on t1.movieId = " \
          "t2.movieId order by t2.rank asc ;;"

    data = execute(sql)
    return data
```

**views.py**

```
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
class Trending(viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    def list(self,request):
        if request.query_params['type']=='trending':
            result_data = models.trending_assets()

            return Response(models.formatter(result_data))
# 
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Wrong Argument pass'},status= 400)
```

Comment: Exactly what is calling `trending_assets`, and from where? Also explain why you're doing this via raw SQL and an explicit connection.

Comment: trending assets just fetches data from asset_ranks table and extra data from content table which is available by inner join on both from mysql db.

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. I can see what it does, I asked you where it was being called from and why you're using raw SQL.

Comment: The function has been called in my views.py file, which I've now included in the above question.The reason behind using raw sql is because it is commonly used way of fetching data from mysql. In most of the tutorial raw sql is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect the db each time you need to when a request need to be processed. Earlier I used a connection globally. And do not use db.close().

```
def execute(query):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='user', password='passsword', db='db_name', port=3306, charset='utf8', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()
    return data


def trending_assets():

    sql = "select * from media_recommendation_engine.content_table t1 inner join (SELECT movieId,rank from" \
          " media_recommendation_engine.asset_ranks limit 10) t2 on t1.movieId = " \
          "t2.movieId order by t2.rank asc ;;"

    data = execute(sql)
    return data
```